# how to get the child node in div using javascript

Tags: javascript, get

Below is the structure of my div:

```
<div id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_Jobs_dlItems_ctl01_a"
    onmouseup="checkMultipleSelection(this,event);">
       <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" width="100%">
           <tr>
              <td style="width:50px; text-align:left;">09:15 AM</td>
              <td style="width:50px; text-align:left;">Item001</td>
              <td style="width:50px; text-align:left;">10</td>
              <td style="width:50px; text-align:left;">Address1</td>
              <td style="width:50px; text-align:left;">46545465</td>
              <td style="width:50px; text-align:left;">ref1</td>
           </tr>
       </table>
</div>
```

Now, if i have the id of the div, how can i get the time and address for this div using JavaScript?

Answer (score 40, accepted):

```
var tds = document.getElementById("ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_Jobs_dlItems_ctl01_a").getElementsByTagName("td");
time = tds[0].firstChild.value;
address = tds[3].firstChild.value;
```

Comment: How do i get div ? When i put divID here, it says , this property is not valid.

Comment: @Khushi using `firstChild.data` or `firstChild.nodeValue` worked for me.

Answer (score 2):

If you give your table a unique id, its easier:

```
<div id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_Jobs_dlItems_ctl01_a"
    onmouseup="checkMultipleSelection(this,event);">
       <table id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_Jobs_dlItems_ctl01_a_table" 
              cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" width="100%">
           <tr>
              <td style="width:50px; text-align:left;">09:15 AM</td>
              <td style="width:50px; text-align:left;">Item001</td>
              <td style="width:50px; text-align:left;">10</td>
              <td style="width:50px; text-align:left;">Address1</td>
              <td style="width:50px; text-align:left;">46545465</td>
              <td style="width:50px; text-align:left;">ref1</td>
           </tr>
       </table>
</div>


var multiselect = 
    document.getElementById(
               'ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_Jobs_dlItems_ctl01_a_table'
            ).rows[0].cells,
    timeXaddr = [multiselect[0].innerHTML, multiselect[2].innerHTML];

//=> timeXaddr now an array containing ['09:15 AM', 'Address1'];
```